# How to check logs for all connections Linux made to servers and/or downloads

Tags: security, log, antivirus

I downloaded Sophos a few days eariler, but now I'm worried I might've got it from a bad source. Is there a way to check to see where I've got it from without using the download list of Chromium (It got deleted.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data is logged by the browser, not by Ubuntu.

If you still have the download you could check the [checksum](https://www.sophos.com/fr-fr/support/knowledgebase/27373.aspx). If that checks out at least you know it is a valid download.

But... you seem to have problems with Sophos and probably are asking for something that does not solve your actual problem ;)

Comment: Well I didn't have too much issues except some slowdown, which partially got fixed after uninstalling it. I also already deleted the install file. Now my boot up takes longer than usual, and I'm trying to see why it's still doing that. However for the most part, not too much. I use Ubuntu Gnome 15.10.

Comment: regarding bootup: activate the bootchart service. it will show you what takes a long time to load during boot.

Comment: How? Also I found the video showing me install Sophos, so I was wanting to recover the wrong video, lol. XD